# How to replace .class file in android.jar

Tags: android, class, bluetooth

Im trying to develop bluetooth app using galaxy s3.
Recently I got a new samsung bluetooth le api. There are two class file, BluetoothDevice.class and BluetoothAdapter.class. I want to replace original class files with it.
Or Are there any other api?
thanks to any comments..

Answer (score 1):

You can't change that library. Try to read the docs and combine them to your project or find another library

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the code of those classes, you can decompile then, make your changes and then recompile.

Comment: Is possible decompile android.jar ?

Comment: Thinking better, you do not even need to decompile, since it is open source.
You can download the source here: [link](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)